# Unity can't resolve interface in Session_Start and resolves wrong DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using Mvc3 and [Unity.Mvc3](http://unitymvc3.codeplex.com/) to build a testable and decoupled site, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

In my `Application_Start()` i register a dependency:

```
// container is a property of the MvcApplication
// and the HierarchicalLifetimeManager should make sure that the registrations
// only last for this request (or should it?)
_container.Register<Interface, Class>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
```

Then in the `Session_Start()` i try to resolve my dependency to save some data into the session:

```
var obj = _container.Resolve<Interface>();
```

At this point I get an exception saying that Unity can't resolve an interface, but I thought I registered a class for that interface???

I'm at a loss, and it's getting harder and harder to find a solution.

**EDIT:**

Here's my whole code, with some unnecessary parts left out:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication  
{   
    // as EDIT 2 says, this is wrong...
    //private IUnityContainer _container = new UnityContainer();
   
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // mvc stuff, routes, areas and whatnot

        // create container here and it works, almost
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register dependencies            
        string connectionString = "String from config";
        container.RegisterInstance<DbContext>(new CustomContext(connectionString), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
                 .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
                 .RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>), new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        // register controller resolver
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

        // if i try to resolve repos here, it works and they all have the same context
        // just like the unit of work
    }

    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        // here the container complains that it can't resolve the interface
         
        // wrong
        //var userRepo = _container.Resolve<IRepository<User>>();

        // right, but still failes, because it is resolving DbContext
        // instead of using the CustomContext instance
        var userRepo = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRepository<User>>();

        // save some user data to session           
    }
}


public class SampleController : Controller {

    // here the container tries to resolve the System.Data.Entity.DbContext
    // instead of just giving the repo that instance that I registered
    public SampleController(IRepository<Entity> repo) {
    }

}
```

I'm obviously failing miserably at this Unit-of-work, dependency injection stuff, and the worst part is that I don't know why...
So please help before I start pulling my teeth out.

**EDIT 2:**

Partly there. If i create the container as above, it fails in the `Session_Start()`. If i create it in the `Application_Start()` as a local variable, and use the `DependencyResolver`, it works. How and why, beats me?

But it's still trying to resolve the `DbContext` instead of the `CustomContext` instance.

**SOLUTION:**

Ok, so here's the deal:

Problem 1) accessing the container in `Session_Start()`:

As described in the EDIT 2, using a local container variable solves that, and accessing the container via the `DependencyResolver` works.

Problem 2) resolving the registered db context instance:

It turns out that registering an instance does not work.
This does though:

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, CustomContext>(null, new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(connectionString))
```

But I don't really feel satisfied, because I still didn't figure out why this works like this. Looks like I need to read a book or something for once in a long time.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting _container from?

Comment: I create an instance in the MvcApplication class, `private IUnityContainer _container = new UnityContainer();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using `RegisterInstance` with the `HierarchecalLifetimeManager`.  I'm guessing you're trying to get a new instance per request, because the Unity.Mvc3 project uses that LifetimeManager to work that magic (as well as HttpModules to manage the creation and destruction of child containers).

The problem is, as a new request comes in, it will want to construct a new object, but doesn't know how to; you just registered an instance once, at the app start, and not a way to make an object.  So you need to use RegisterType() for that to work.

You have two choices:

1. Specify the injected value using an InjectionConstructor: `RegisterType<DbContext, CustomContext>(new HierarchecalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(connectionString))`
2. Use a factory: `Container.RegisterType<DbContext>(new InjectionFactory(c => new CustomContext(connectionString)), new HierarcicalLifetimeManager())` ([inspired by this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771097/ioc-register-instance-issue-with-mvc3-unity-nhibernate-unity-mvc3-lib-from))

*Note: parameter order may be wrong.

If you want a true singleton instance for your entire application, use the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()` (which is actually the default for RegisterInstance, so you don't even need to specify it).  But then your DbContext will get rather huge as the site gets used.

Additionally, on your initial problem with the items not being registered in Session_Start():

ASP.NET maintains a pool of HttpApplication classes.  That means if you make the Unity container a member variable, you'll have several instances which all have their own registrations.  Application_Start() is called only once, and Session_Start() could be called using a different instance with no registrations.  You'd need to use a static variable to solve that (which is what you ended up doing with the DependencyResolver).

Comment: Actually, the registration under 1) is what I tried later and it worked. I just put the wrong code snippet in my question edit (it was really late by then).
But thanks for the explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing the container directly (it's not clear from your Q where you got the reference to the container?), why not let the MVC dependency resolver resolve it?

Set the Dependency resolver (Application_Start()):

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Resolve your interface (Session_Start()):

```
var obj = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyInterface>();
```

Comment: I actually do use the UnityDependencyResolver. I'll see if using it in the Session_Start will work. But it would be weird, since it just delegates to what I did in the question.

Comment: It kinda worked so +1, but with some other modifications... I'm still not quite there yet..

Comment: I'm accepting this since it did lead me to the solution, but for anyone that has a similar problem, read the whole thing first...

Comment: Does your CustomContext class inherit from DbContext?

Comment: Yes it does. It works when I do `registerType`, which is total weirdness. I don't know why I can't just register an instance.